# How to Set a Users Attribute of msExchArchiveGUID with Hexidecimal using Set-ADUser in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I need to set some attributes for users and I need to be able to add a hexidecimal value for msExchArchiveGUID and my script errors at this point.  I took a manual look and there is a drop down box that you choose from Hexidecimal, Binary, Decimal, or Octal and Hexidecimal is what I need for the value.  My value for $Hex = 2a 1b ba 59 ff 5e 00 4c 89 b8 2a af fd c1 fc 23

Below is my script and all the values work except for the msExchArchiveGUID

```
# Import Information
$Information = Import-Csv "c:\scripts\GUIDIssue\UPNList.csv"

# Convert cloud archive GUID to AD Hex format
foreach ($Info in $Information) {
    # Get AD Hex from GUID
    [system.guid]$guid = $Info.CloudArchiveGUID 
    $Hex = ($Guid.ToByteArray() | foreach { $_.ToString('x2') }) -Join ' ' 

    <#
    Set Values for the following

    Msexchrecipientdisplaytype  1073741824
    msExchRecipientTypeDetails  1
    msExchRemoteRecipientType   3
    msexcharchiveguid   “$Hex”
    msexcharchivestatus 1
    mailnickname    “$Info.SAM”
    #>

    Set-ADUser `
        -Identity $Info.SAM -Replace @{
            Msexchrecipientdisplaytype="1073741824";
            msExchRecipientTypeDetails="1";
            msExchRemoteRecipientType="3";
            msexcharchivestatus="1";
            mailnickname=$Info.SAM;
            msexcharchiveguid=$Hex
        }
    # Sync AD
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
}
```

Comment: `-Replace @{msExchArchiveGUID=$Hex.ToByteArray()}`

Comment: I get this error:  Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ToByteArray'.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$Guid.ToByteArray()`, not `$Hex.ToByteArray()`